# comparing two arrays of coordinates and merging array based on their distances

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

hope doing well.
I want to compare thousands of points in the space and assign the attribute of one data set to another one. I have my attributes and ccordinates of each point as numpy arrays.

```
arr_1 = [[10,  0, 0, 0],
         [30, 0, 0, 5],
         [5, 0, 0, 10],
         [1, 0, 0, 15],
         [16, 0, 5, 0],
         [39, 0, 10, 0],
         ...
         [2, 15, 15, 15]]
```

The first column of this array is my attribute and other three ones are x, y and z, respectively. My coordinate is increasing firstly by z (fourth column), then y (second column) and finally x (first column). Now, I have another set of coordinate data from the same space. The new data is gathered from some points which are not the same as x,y and z of arr_1. The length of these two arrays are not the same. Coordinates are not sorted here and they are choatic. In this array also the first column is my property and other ones are x, y and z:

```
arr_2 = [[1, 0.45, 9, 18],
         [2, 10, 12, 0],
         [4, 14, 15, 16],
         [1, 17, 3, 1],
         [5, 0, 11, 10],
         [1, 5, 9, 12.5],
         ...]
```

Now, I want to have a code that compares the location of each point (each row) of  `arr_2` with all the points of of  `arr_1` and finds out which point (row) of  `arr_2` is closer to which point of `arr_1`. Then I want to copy the attribute column (first one) of `arr_1` into the closet point of `arr_2`. In the other words, I can say two data sets are gathered from a different points of an area. Now, I want to merge them, but firstly I should find out which points are adjacent and then merge their properties into one array.
In advance, I appreciate any solution.
Cheers,
Ali

Comment: And your attempt at solving the problem is?

Comment: Honestly, I couldn’t figure it out. I could just write some codes to measure the Euclidian distance between all the rows, but it was useless in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do that but I appreciate you for suggesting more efficient solutions. My code is presented in the following:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
dist=distance.cdist(arr_1[:,1:3],arr_2[:,1:3])
indices_dist_min=np.argmin(dist, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
z=np.array([])
for i in indices_dist_min:
    u=arr_2[i,0]
    z=np.array([np.append(z,u)]).reshape(-1,1)
arr_3=np.concatenate((arr_1,z), axis =1)
```

I appreciate any other solution, or correct me if I am in the wrong way.
Cheers,
Ali